# Check the duplicated data from two different list

Tags: python, list

I got a list of data in csv file and I have call 'Types' columns in Python. I would like to check the duplicate data between the output and the labels list and display which data is duplicated.

For example, the result I expected in output 0 is

```
'spa', 'lodging'
```

call 'Types' columns

```
place_type = csv['Types']
```

output:

```
0      ['spa', 'lodging', 'point_of_interest', 'estab...
1      ['spa', 'beauty_salon', 'hair_care', 'point_of...
2          ['spa', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
3      ['beauty_salon', 'hair_care', 'spa', 'point_of...
4          ['spa', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
                             ...                        
991    ['tourist_attraction', 'point_of_interest', 'e...
992    ['tourist_attraction', 'point_of_interest', 'e...
993    ['zoo', 'tourist_attraction', 'point_of_intere...
994    ['tourist_attraction', 'point_of_interest', 'e...
995    ['tourist_attraction', 'point_of_interest', 'e..
```

I called a for loop to make the duplication can go through all the place_type

```
for i in place_type:
  print (i)
  a=set(labels).intersection(i)
  print(a)
```

labels list

```
labels = ['amusement_park', 'campground', 'park', 'tourist_attraction', 'zoo',
          'clothing_store', 'department_store', 'library', 'lodging', 'movie_theater', 'shopping_mall', 'spa',
          'bakery' , 'bar', 'cafe', 'convenience_store', 'liquor_store', 'night_club', 'restaurant', 'store',
          'art_gallery', 'church', 'hindu_temple', 'mosque', 'museum', 'aquarium', 'synagogue']
```

Comment: `set(labels).intersection(['spa', 'lodging', 'point_of_interest'])` gives `{'lodging', 'spa'}`. Try `set`

Comment: This work when I specified a list to it, but is not working when I use for loop 


for i in place_type:
  print (i)
  a=set(labels).intersection(i)
  print(a)

Comment: `set(a).intersection(b)` demands `b` should be a iterable. You just do `set(labels).intersection(place_type) `

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to compare those collections as sets

Just a usage example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [2, 3, 4]

duplicates = set(list1) & set(list2)  # {2, 3}
```

so in your case it would be something like this:

```
labels_set = set(labels)
duplicates = set(result[0]) & labels_set  # {'spa', 'lodging'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a nested loop, which iterates over both lists.

```
output = []
list1 = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
list2 = ['test4', 'test2', 'test3']
for elem1 in list1:
    for elem2 in list2:
        if elem1 == elem2:
            output.append(elem1)

print(output)
```

output:

```
['test2', 'test3']
```